# SignalR .net core client in .NET framework 4 apllication

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, signalr, nancy, self-hosting

I have 2 applications:

1. NetCore 2.2 web-application
2. .Net Framework 4 web-application (owin, nancy-framework). For some reasons I cant upgrade target net framework version in this
   application.

There is a requirement to provide ***two-way connection***. In other words, I want to send commands from **1st app** to **2nd app**.

*More about the situation*:
With current network organization I can make request from **2-app** to **1-app**, it works successfully. 
But ***I can't make request from*** **1-app** to **2-app** (host of 2nd app is not pingable from 1st app). I was hoping to solve the problem with SignalR library, but it has platform-depend limitations (signalR Core client library in old applications,  [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) package).

How can i solve this problem? Maybe I have some alternatives?

Comment: As you mentioned, the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client) could not be installed in .NET framework 4 appliation. If you can clarify more about the requirement/scenario, we can understand and help achieve it better.

Comment: I was edit my question. If this does not explain the problem - I will try again)

Comment: you need a .net standard 2.0 compatible .net framework (4.7.2 or 4.8)

Comment: indeed ! thx magicandre1981